# Dynamically delete jenkins build if it fails and reset build number

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am able to delete failed jenkins build by:

```
   - Going to console output for failed jenkins build
   - Delete build (option from left column)
   - Then set next build number to the build number just deleted.
```

However, I am looking for a way to do this as part of jenkins job itself. 
If the build fails can it be set to delete build and reset build number?